# Ubuntu 13.04 lenovo m490 INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy

Tags: wireless

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 (latest updates, kernel 3.8.0-25-generic) on this machine and got several issues:

When I restart the laptop the monitor displays:

```
[    9.171781] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
```

I don't know if it's a known bug in this combination. The issue is common
known on other hardware configs.

```
[eric@Ubuntu:shell]$ dmesg | grep cfg80211
[    9.126810] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    9.171781] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
[    9.372793] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    9.372797] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[    9.372798] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    9.372799] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    9.372800] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    9.372801] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    9.372802] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.114689] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[   16.117140] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[   16.117143] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   16.117144] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[   16.117145] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[   16.117146] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.117147] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.117148] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.117149] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
```

I get the message.

I hope anyone can help me to identify if it's a bug or not.

Comment: I get the same message in 13.10 on my Lenovo Z565. Doesn't affect the boot, except perhaps slowing it down.

Comment: Looks like a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1160322

Comment: @Glutanimate is not a bug. Just a **INFO** message.

Comment: @Braiam I don't think it's intended behaviour to disrupt the boot up process with an extra black screen and info message. It doesn't matter if it has no effects on the WLAN function. An annoying message that might scare some users is just as much of a bug as an error that compromises the whole system. In this case I can talk out of personal experience as I am facing the same issue. And I can most definitely tell you that this is something new that has never occurred for me before Linux 3.8.

Comment: @Glutanimate if you check the "bug" report, you will see that is marked as `INVALID` and the very message you see starts with `INFO` `[    9.171781] **INFO** @wl_cfg80211_attach`. In any case my answer is correct, and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Braiam No, Braiam, the bug report isn't marked as invalid. It was marked as expired because of lack of activity. No one doubts that this is an info message but it should most definitely not be there. As such it is a bug, albeit a comparatively harmless one.

Answer (score 2):

According with [this comment:](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1160322/comments/5)

> I got the same message on startup, but I don't think it's a bug. Just it's annoying message on startup

Next:

> The same INFO message for me: I have the message each time at startup just before Ubuntu splash screen.

Is just a message, nothing to be scared of.