# Odd start up, blank then error, then quick boot 13.10

Tags: installation, boot, brightness

When I boot up sometimes I get:

BIOS, blank purple screen for a bit, a black screen with printed on it:

```
[      10.838171]  INFO 0w1_cfg80211_attach  :  Registered CFG80211 phy
```

then the orange dot ubuntu load screen that goes quickly.

Is this normal?  Should it be the white dot ubuntu logo load screen the whole time?

I've recently wiped my entire drive (DBAN autonuke) from having ubuntu and windows to just ubuntu.

---

Also I frequently get freezes in situations and have to hard reboot.
How do I know badly my hard rebooting has damaged my drive, how do I/can I fix it?

It happens when I use the F-keys to adjust my brightness, I stopped using them.
It happens when I `sudo halt` from the command line, `sudo reboot` works fine though.

And it happened a lot with ubuntu live USB's i was using and using gParted.

---

Another side question, I think I enabled LVM on my most recent installation, how do I check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of off-topic post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/311281/ubuntu-13-04-lenovo-m490-info-wl-cfg80211-attach-registered-cfg80211-phy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug as reported here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1160322

It should not effect your boot or your operating system. It appears to be related to your wireless card. I would not be concerned.

Comment: thanks Could this be because I was using the proprietary software driver for my broadcom wireless device?  I've disabled the propitiate software, will check next boot.